# Is there an alternative for case by case "if" statements for comparing an input integer with multiple ranges?

Tags: python

First semester python student here, so this is probably a very basic and stupid question.

I have 4 sets of ranges:

```
age=int(input("Enter your age: "))
range1=range(0,12)
range2=range(13,19)
range3=range(20,64)
range4=range(65,100)
```

I want it to display the corresponding range of the input integer without using 4 sets of `if age in rangeX` statements, is there any way to do this?

Comment: use a *container*, like a list. Loop over the list, and use a single conditional in the body of the loop. Whenver you see yourself doing `x1 = something1; x2 = something1, x3 = something3, ..., xn = somethingn` then you really just need `xs = []`

Comment: Also note that `range` is a half-open interval in Python, so `range(0,12)` contains 0-11.  Your ranges above don't include 12, 19, 64 or 100.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use dictionaries in python as an alternative of switch/case like statements in other languages. Each value of dictionary can be a function to do the job. For example you can do something like below:

```
age_range_detector = {
    range(0, 12): lambda: print("Kid"),
    range(13,19): lambda: print("Young"),
    range(20,64): lambda: print("Middle-aged"),
    range(65,100): lambda: print("Old"),
}
```

In order to use this dictionary:

```
def get_age_func(age):
    for k, v in age_range_detector.items():
        if age in k:
            return v
```

and call returned function from this function:

```
get_age_func()()
```

Comment: @Brainalingus that's a complete misuse of a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

```
ranges = [range(0,12), range(13,19), range(20,64), range(65,100)]

n = 97

for r in ranges:
    if n in r:
        print(f"{r[0]} - {r[-1]}")
```

Create a list of ranges, loop over it, and if the number is within that range, print the range.  Keep in mind that the range doesn't include the second argument.

The above prints:

```
69 - 99
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_of_ranges = [range1, range2, range3, range4]
for a_range in list_of_ranges:
    if age in a_range:
        print(a_range)
```

if the ranges are not overlapping, you can add a break in order to avoid doing the cycle after you found the correct range

Comment: Thanks! That worked, is there a way for it to print as "range1" or "range2" etc. as opposed to "range (13,20)"

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

````
age = int(input("Enter your age: "))
print(next((r for r in [range1, range2, range3, range4] if age in r), None))
```
````